# Failed opening required database.inc (attempting to use drupal)

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to setup a drupal web server with FreeBSD.

When I try to access the drupal index i am greeted with:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
>   '/usr/local/www/apache24/data/drupal/includes/database/sqlite/database.inc'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/local/share/pear') in
>   /usr/local/www/apache24/data/drupal/includes/database/database.inc on
>   line 1685

I am new to freeBSD but i tried setting chmod 667 to the:

```
sqlite/database.inc
database/database.inc
sqlite
database
```

Also, i do not understand why it is looking for `/usr/local/share/pear`as there is no such directory.

I am using MySQL55, PHP5, Drupal-7, and Apache.

I think this might be related but when i access the install.php i get:

Undefined index: distribution_name in drupal_install_profile_distribution_name() (line 201 of /usr/local/www/apache24/data/drupal/includes/install.inc).

Comment: update, after foing the following, it no longer instantly times out with an error:

chmod u+rwx,g+rwx,o+wrx database/sqlite/database.inc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you use drush?

That looks as if you already installed drupal, or at least drupal thinks so. and also with the wrong database settings. normally, you will be prompted to enter them in the web interface, but you also can enter them directly in the settings php. Propably you should just move the old settings.php and run install.php in your browser and enter the database details anew.

drupal_install_profile_distribution_name can be changed in the database under system->standard_profile  and variable->install_profiles directly or using drush (www.drush.ws) with

vset install_profile *standard*

or any other install profile you used.

Anyways, the install script asks for that as well.

hope, this was your problem.

Comment: I did 'install' drupal with drush. is there a drush command i can use to deinstall i, or what would be the best way to do so?

Comment: I got this now. Seems like downloading and extracting it manually instead of using drush is easier to do.

Comment: yip :) Even though drush is a very cool tool, for initial setup I prefer the drupal install.php. When you run a couple of test sites a day, that might be different...